# Classification in QGIS with modifications in Lizmap

Tags: qgis, lizmap

I'm trying to make some changes to some fields of a point layer in Lizmap. Currently the changes I make are updated in the DB.
I'm looking for a way to dynamically manage the classification done in QGIS. For example I have some time slots:
F1 - F2 I would like to rename the classification made or I would like to make sure to leave only F1.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots, the question is not really clear. Do you mean the classification renderer in the legend ? If you don't use any expression, no it's not possible, as the legend is written in the QGS file, even in dekstop, you need to press the "Recompute" button, right ?

Comment: exactly, I have a database that is always fed by new data.
This means that I have to reclassify every time.
Furthermore, when carrying out a classification, if a user who works on lizmap modifies the field on which the classification is carried out, I also have to reclassify them